# xamarin Is it possible to create Android .AAR file from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, aar

I need to generate Android archive (.AAR) file from my Xamarin project. AAR file is required for embedding the app generated via Xamarin to an another android app which is developed in Android studio. So is there any option that i can generate AAR file from my xamarin project or if any other work around is possible so that i can embed my xamarin app to android app?.

Comment: I have similar situation, Are there some way to do it?